# Convert Lat/Lon from Decimal, minute, seconds (00000000) to integer coordinates (00.000000)

Tags: excel

I have 182 sets of Decimal Minute Second (DMS) Coordinates I need to convert to Integer Coordinates. I have a code for conversion from a certain format (`00° 00' 00.00"`) but cannot format my data to that format from `00000000`. The Issue seems to be that I cannot use a " in a custom format. When I manually add the DMS symbols to the data the code I have works.

I have tried to format the cell to look like `00° 00' 00.00"` but it returns the error

> "Excel cannot use the number format you typed."

I know the " is the issue as I was able to enter formats discluding that symbol but containing the other two.

```
Function Convert_Decimal(Degree_Deg As String) As Double
   ' Declare the variables to be double precision floating-point.
   Dim degrees As Double
   Dim minutes As Double
   Dim seconds As Double
   ' Set degree to value before "°" of Argument Passed.
   degrees = Val(Left(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") - 1))
   ' Set minutes to the value between the "°" and the "'"
   ' of the text string for the variable Degree_Deg divided by
   ' 60. The Val function converts the text string to a number.
   minutes = Val(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") + 2, _
             InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, _
             "°") - 2)) / 60
    ' Set seconds to the number to the right of "'" that is
    ' converted to a value and then divided by 3600.
    seconds = Val(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") + _
            2, Len(Degree_Deg) - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - 2)) _
            / 3600
   Convert_Decimal = degrees + minutes + seconds
End Function
```

This code works as expected, but I cannot format my data to work with this code.

I did not write that code, and I have little experience writing code, could I change this code to not need the " symbol or change the symbol required to one I can format into my data?

Is there an easier way of converting my data from DMS to Integer coordinates?

Comment: can you give some examples of your actual input and what you would expect as an output?

Comment: the text formula is actually: `=TEXT(A1,"0#\° 0#\' 0#\.00\""")`

Comment: so using your UDF you would do: `=Convert_Decimal(TEXT(A1,"0#\° 0#\' 0#\.00\"""))` But you can also skip the UDF: `=LEFT(A1,2)+MID(A1,3,2)/60+RIGHT(A1,4)/360000` and just do the parsing and math.

Comment: Not sure what you want without examples of your data and desired output. But to custom format a cell to display a number in your desired format (including the `"`), you can use:  `00° 00' 00.00\"`